# How to restrict the credits allocated for an user under an organization / domain in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam, google-cloud-billing, google-cloud-identity

Is it possible to fix the maximum quota (of credits) usable by an user?
For example, fixing a limit of 1000 USD for a particular user per month or year.

What I have looked at so far:
1. [Guide to Cloud Billing Resource Organization & Access Management](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/onboarding-checklist)
2. [Working with Quotas](https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota)
3. [How-to Guides -- Cloud Billing](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to)
4. [Resource Quotas](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas)

I believe none of these articles have the answer. So, please atleast let me know if it's possible.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible per user, you can only set [budget alerts](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/budgets) on project, with several threshold for notification, and ONLY FOR NOTIFICATION. The project won't be shut down in case of limit reached.

You can also send these alerts into PubSub and then perform some special operation, like deactivate the billing on the project (and thus stop totally the project). There is an example [here](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/notify#cap_disable_billing_to_stop_usage)

This limitation is not perfect, in particular when users use BigQuery. If a user do anything, the whole project is impacted. About BigQuery, billed byte limitations should be released, a day.

Comment: The budget alerts seem to be on a per-month basis. It would have been better if there was atleast an option to set the complete budget for a project throughout some period, like an year or something.